# Where to place “auch” in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I’m having a bit of trouble placing “auch” in the German translation of “I also love my cat”. Would it be “Ich auch liebe meine Katze” or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how this *auch* is meant: Like *In addition to my other pets, I love my cat* or *Just like all the other cat owners, I love my cat*. I think the most fitting position of *auch* in your sentence heavily depends on the context.

Answer (score 11):

There are three possibilities:

> Auch ich liebe meine Katze

*I, too, love my cat* (if you specifically want to focus that it's you, too)

> Ich liebe meine Katze auch

*I love my cat, too*

> Ich liebe auch meine Katze

*I also love my cat* (in addition to your dog, rabbit, child, whatever)

Comment: Funnily op found one of two places where "auch" cannot be placed in this sentence... the only other "wrong" position would be between "meine" and "Katze"...

Comment: I think the first possibility, *Auch ich ...*, might be open to interpretation. Could it also mean "Even I (a well known curmudgeon) love my cat"?

Comment: @RDBury I think that would be "sogar ich"

Comment: Agreed. *Auch ich liebe meine Katze* implies other cat lovers, as it were.